# Why is the acute angle projection in linear algebra not satisfy idempotency ($P^2 = P$)?

Tags: linear-algebra

There is a question in Sheldon Axler's Linear Algebra Done Right that asks:

Prove that if $P \in L(V)$ is such that $P^2 =P$ and $||Pv|| \leq ||v||$ for every $v \in V$, then $P$ is an orthogonal projection.

I started to play around with the definition and wanted to understand the contrapositive a bit better, which is that if $P$ **ISN'T** an orthogonal projection, i.e., acute or obtuse, (at least in the 2-D space), then $P^2 \neq P$ and $||Pv|| \geq ||v||$ for every $v \in V$.

For the obtuse case, I can draw it out in 2-D and see that the projection distance is indeed greater than the vector. But in the acute case, $||Pv|| \leq ||v||$ for every $v \in V$ holds and so it must obviously be the idempotency of $P$ that fails. However, I do not really understand why it fails in the acute angle case. Meaning, I dont really understand what it means to take the projection of a projection. Can anyone help me shed light into my problem?

I basically would love to be able to understand the contrapositive from a geometric standpoint. Thank you!!

Comment: What do you mean by an "acute" or "obtuse" projection.

Comment: The contrapositive is "If P is not an orthogonal projection then $P^2$ is not P or $||Pv||\geq||v||$ for some v".

Comment: You're making a false distinction between "acute" and "obtuse" projections.  The angle between two vectors may be acute or obtuse, but *subspaces* are closed under negation: if there is an acute angle between two subspaces, then there is also an obtuse one.  You'd really need to draw a picture of what you're thinking in order for us to diagnose the misconception.  But for starters, all projections are idempotent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You got the contrapositive wrong. It says that if $P$ is not an orthogonal projection, then **either** $P\notin L(V)$ **or** $P^2\neq P$ **or** there exists some $v\in V$ with $\|Pv\|>\|v\|$. Or, if you take $P\in L(V)$ out of the conditional as just stating the type of $P$, it could be taken to say that if $P\in L(V)$ is not an orthogonal projection, then either $P^2\neq P$ or there exists some $v\in V$ with $\|Pv\|>\|v\|$. In any case it is the final condition that holds for non-orthogonal projections: the image of some vectors increases in norm. All projections do satisfy $P^2=P$.

Answer (score 2):

Let $x\in\ker p$ and $y\in\operatorname{im }p$ then $p(y+tx)=p(y)=y$ hence
$$||y||^2=||p(y)||^2\le||y+tx||^2,\quad \forall t$$
hence we find
$$P(t)=t^2||x||^2+2t\langle x,y\rangle\ge0,\quad\forall t$$
hence the discriminant $\langle x,y\rangle^2$  of the quadratic polynomial $P$ is non positive hence
$$\langle x,y\rangle=0$$
and the desired result follows.

Answer (score 0):

Assume that $P: \mathbb R^n\to \mathbb R^n$.

If $P^2=P$, then the polynomial $p(x)=x^2-x$ annihilates $P$ and hence $P$ is diagonalizable, with all its eigenvalues in $\{0,1\}$.

Let $E_0=\{x: Px=0\}$ and $E_1=\{x:Px=x\}$. Then $\mathbb R^n=E_0\oplus E_1$.

It suffices to show that the subspaces $E_0$ and $E_1$ are perpendicular, i.e., if $x\in E_0$ and $y\in E_1$, then $(x,y)=0$. Assume the contrary, i.e., for  some $x\in E_0$ and $y\in E_1$, then $(x,y)=a\ne 0$. Set $z=\lambda x+ y$, where 
$$
\lambda=-\frac{\|y\|^2}{a}.
$$
Then

$$
\|\lambda x+y\|^2=\lambda^2 \|x\|^2+2\lambda (x,y)+\|y\|^2=\lambda^2 \|x\|^2+2\lambda a+\|y\|^2=\lambda^2 \|x\|^2-\|y\|^2
<\lambda^2 \|x\|^2,
$$
which implies that
$$
\|z\|^2<\|Tz\|^2.
$$